# Get User Username from Firebase Table Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get the username from my users table using the post uid from my posts table, so i can display it in my feed.

this is the code i am using. i have been trying for a while and cannot get around it, nothing is showing but it prints the usernames in the console

```
final class Post: ListDiffable {


    // 1

    let strainId: String
    let postId: String
    let timestamp: NSNumber
    let caption: String
    let likes: Int
    var user = UserStruct()
    var uid = String()
    var date = String()
    var location = String()
    var data = [ImageDataStruct]()
    var username = String()


    // 2
    init(postId : String, timestamp: NSNumber, caption:String, strainId:String , likes: Int , profilePhoto: URL , uid:String , data:[ImageDataStruct] , user: UserStruct ) {


        self.timestamp = timestamp
        self.likes = likes
        self.caption = caption
        self.postId = postId
        self.strainId = strainId
        self.uid = uid

        self.user = user

        self.data = data


    }

    init(snap: DataSnapshot) {

        let userDict = snap.value as! [String:Any]

        self.likes = userDict["likes"] as! Int
        self.postId = userDict["productId"] as! String
        self.uid = userDict["userID"] as! String
        self.caption = userDict["caption"] as! String
        self.timestamp = userDict["timestamp"] as! NSNumber
        self.date = userDict["date"] as! String
        self.location = userDict["location"] as! String
        self.strainId = userDict["strainid"] as! String
        let productImages = userDict["productImages"] as! [[String:String]]

        var imgStruct = [ImageDataStruct]()

        for data in productImages {


            let dict = data as! [String:String]

            var temp = ImageDataStruct()

            temp.size = dict["size"] as? String
            temp.type = dict["type"] as? String
            temp.url = dict["url"] as? String

            imgStruct.append(temp)
        }

        print(uid)

        Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { [weak self] snapshot in

            let user = User(snap: snapshot)

            self?.username = user.userID
            self?.user.username = self?.username

        })



    }



    func diffIdentifier() -> NSObjectProtocol {
        // 1
        return (postId ) as NSObjectProtocol
    }

    // 2
    func isEqual(toDiffableObject object: ListDiffable?) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

please can somebody help!

Comment: How does this code print the user names to the console? There's only one print statement. Also, the User class is not included so we don't know what that does. Lastly, right after this statement `let user = User(snap: snapshot)` add `print(user.username` and see if it prints anything. If it does then the issue is after that line. If it doesn't it means your Firebase function isn't returning any data in the snapshot *or* the User class is not correct.

Comment: it prints the usernames but after it gets the posts

Comment: the posts get retrieved then after its loaded into the collection view the users after then printed

Comment: You may want to re-read my comment/question. You're stating that usernames print but there's **NO code in the question that prints usernames**. Did you try the things I suggested in my comment? What was the result? Also, there's no code in your question that gets posts - the only thing you're retrieving from firebase is a specific user - see this `Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(uid)`. Can you update and clarify your question as it's quote confusing.